# Call a component with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component 1 (Movies) and I want to call to component 2 (Movie):

Movies:

```
return (
    <>
    <div>
        <h2>Movies</h2>
    </div>     

    <Grid container spacing={2} >
        { movies.map((movie) =>                 
         **   <Movie data={ movie }></Movie> **
        )}
    </Grid>
    </>
);
```

Movie:

```
const Pelicula = ( {data} ) => {

 console.log("a ", data );
};
```

I could not get any information in component 2, any recommendation for that?

Comment: Are you sure your movies data is correct ? What does it look like ?

Comment: movies data has information in Component 1 but I don't know what happens when I try to use data in Component 2, I am new in React so I'd like to know if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is incorrectly named, the component is defined as `Pelicula`, but in the `Movies` component, it is called as `Movie`.
The fix could be either renaming the `Pelicula` component to `Movie` or calling the correctly named component, as such:

```js
...
     { movies.map((movie) =>                 
         <Pelicula data={ movie }></Pelicula>
     )}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have changed the name but is the same issue